# Express the rectangular coordinate $(-3,4,-12)$ into spherical coordinates of form $(\rho, \theta, \phi)$. What is $\tan\theta+\tan\phi$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Express the rectangular coordinate $(-3,4,-12)$ into spherical coordinates of form $(\rho, \theta, \phi)$. What is $\tan\theta+\tan\phi$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$r=\sqrt{9+16}=5$$
$$\tan\theta=\frac{4}{-3}=-\frac{4}{3}$$
$$\rho=\sqrt{25+144}=13$$
$$\cos\phi=\frac{-12}{13}$$
$$\tan\phi=\frac{5}{-12}=-\frac{5}{12}$$
Lastly,
$$\tan\theta + \tan\phi=-\frac{4}{3}-\frac{5}{12}=-\frac{7}{4}$$

Comment: hmm your $\tan\phi$ is off. It is supposed to be $\frac{-5}{12}$...

Comment: @Bloop ah okay, let me edit. thanks